Cannot Install Ubuntu 24.04 from USB on Lenovo Legion Pro 7 16ARX8H
Model: Lenovo Legion Pro 7 16ARX8H, Firmware version: LPCN45WW
Issue: Cannot load Ubuntu 24.04 from the USB disk. I can load Grub. If i select "Try or install Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu (safe graphics)", system prints some messages includes errors and then restart. I cannot load the Ubuntu.
Installation from USB stick problem
Tried:

Tried: Disable Secure boot.
Tried disable external graphics in UEFI. So the device can uses only integrated AMD Radeon graphics.
Tried Select: Ubuntu (safe graphics).
Tried run "Ubuntu (safe graphics)" with "nomodeset", but that parameter was already there.
Tried USB disk on another device Dell and I can load Ubuntu without any problems so USB disk is fine.
Tried Ubuntu 22.04.4 and it works.
Windows fast start disabled.

Solution: Solved by load Ubuntu from another USB stick.
Windows 11 vs Grub and booting problem
I thought it was solved, but:

Ok, I could load Ubuntu from USB stick by Samsung. Kingston USB stick does not work. I do not why..

Next problem during installation. The Ubuntu installation wizard was automatically closed during the installation process...hmm, so I wait 20 minutes CPU and network was not active so I restart the laptop (because I do not know installation status).

Three restarts from Ubuntu to Ubuntu was without any problem. Then I restart to Windows 11 and then to Ubuntu and Ubuntu boot does not work: boot loop before show Ubuntu logo while starting... there is no error message (or I do not know how to display it.).

Run Ubuntu 6.8.0-35-generic (recovery mode) and run: dpkg and grub. Does not help. When I add run repair file system (fsck), I can load Ubuntu without any problem.

OK, some restarts from Ubuntu to Ubuntu are OK. Now I tested restart to Windows, It's OK, but when I try to restart from Windows, Grub is totally is missing and I can start only Windows.

OK, I followed the instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEfW_XJzhbI but still when I once boot to Windows then I cannot boot to Ubuntu.


Windows is causing problems!
Bypass solution: when you want to restart from Windows -> Ubuntu, loading Ubuntu always freezes. You have to shutdown Windows. Then turn on laptop and Ubuntu loads fine. It's probably related with -> https://superuser.com/questions/1830599/windows-11-keeps-messing-with-grub-at-every-restart-possible-solution?newreg=44e927a7d80143bcb5c773aaa37528ce
Screenshots:



I disabled it. Does not help.

Can someone explain the downvote? The question is very well-written.

@Raffles: I would like to install Ubuntu 24.04 and have dual boot with Windows 11 (already preinstalled from manufacturer). On my older laptop Dell and all previous laptopts dual boot works always well. I always create a new partion in Ubuntu installer.
There is option in UEFI to set "Change the SATA Operation mode to AHCI from either IDE or RAID (again, the language varies"

Solved, see in the question.

OK, not solved. I could load installation process -> installation window was close during the installation (do not why?) -> ok, wait 20 minutes, CPU and network was not active so I restart the laptop (because I do not know installation process). Three restarts from Ubuntu to Ubuntu was OK. Then I restart to Windows, next restart to Ubuntu and Ubuntu does not work: boot loop before show Ubuntu logo while starting... safe graphics mode does not help..ahh what is wrong, Lenovo or Ubuntu :-(

An now I am on the same situation with Samsung USB like with Kingston. I cannot load Ubuntu from USB. It's crazy.

The Windows 11 causes both problems:

Installation from USB stick problem (see in question)
Rebooting from Windows to Ubuntu problem (see in question)

Bypass solution: when you want to restart from Windows -> Ubuntu, loading Ubuntu (or installation from USB) always freezes. You have to shutdown Windows. Then turn on laptop and Ubuntu loads fine. It's probably related with -> https://superuser.com/questions/1830599/windows-11-keeps-messing-with-grub-at-every-restart-possible-solution?newreg=44e927a7d80143bcb5c773aaa37528ce
